# Is there a way to have the Xcode UI and the Xcode command line tools build with same dependencies?

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode project.
I can build it with the Xcode UI and all is fine.

But if after it is fully built, if I use xcodebuild to build the same scheme as I built in the UI it rebuilds the whole thing.

Is there a way to make the command line build do an incremental build lets say if I have built it all with the UI and change one file ?

Also vice versa if I built it all with the command line, open the UI and modify one file ? and then build in the UI ?